# Getting TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: framework/dotnet.js

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-auto

I had a Blazor Server project which was running on .Net Core 7.0. I ported it to .Net 8.0 Blazor Web App and then tried to run it on Interactive Auto render mode. Then I set up the IIS to run my website exactly how it was on Server project. But when I run the application, I get the TypeError as:
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: /_framework/dotnet.js

Initially I though maybe the base URL could the issue but then this should have caused my CSS and blazor.web.js to also error out, but it was properly set to the application under the Default Web Site.

If I publish the site and run the application, I don't get this error.
If instead of IIS, I use IIS Express the application runs without the above TypeError.

So, what exactly is happening here and how to rid this error?
Or does it mean, dotnet.js will not load during Debug session? If so, what could be the rationale behind this?

Converted Blazor Server app to Render Mode Auto Blazor Web App, on running the site from IIS, it throws a 404 error for dotnet.js which is not seen if the site is published or running through IIS Express.